# Find a TextView from a View that has been Inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, android-view, android-inflate

In Xamarin, if I `Inflate` a `View`, how can I set the text of a `TextView` in the `View`?

I am wanting to code an application where I can call methods in different fragments to pass values between fragments and display these values.

Here is my `MainActivity` code:

```
public class MainActivity : FragmentActivity
{
    string message;

    FragmentOrange fragOrange;
    FragmentGreen fragGreen;
    FragmentRed fragRed;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        fragOrange = new FragmentOrange ();
        fragGreen = new FragmentGreen ();
        fragRed = new FragmentRed ();

        List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment> fragments = new List<Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment>();
        fragments.Add(fragOrange);
        fragments.Add(fragGreen);
        fragments.Add(fragRed);

        MyPagerAdapter pageAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager, fragments);
        var pager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.myViewPager);
        pager.Adapter = pageAdapter;

        pager.SetCurrentItem (0, true);
        fragOrange.SetMessage ("Fragment orange");
    }
}
```

Here is my `FragmentOrange` code:

```
public class FragmentOrange : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
{
    string message;
    TextView textViewDisplay;
    View view;

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_orange, container, false);
        textViewDisplay = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
        return view;
    }

    public void SetMessage(string value)
    {
        message = value;
        textViewDisplay.Text = value;
    }
}
```

When I call the `SetMessage` function, I get the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

At this line of code:

```
textViewDisplay.Text = value;
```

Here is my `Layout` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question with log cat

Answer (score 0):

```
var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
```

should be

```
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplay);
```

please note, that you cannot update a textview from an activity without a handler, as it is a part of the UI.

```
//before oncreate
private int i;
Handler handler;

//oncreate
i = 0;
        handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(mUpdate);

//before the last closing bracket in your activity
     Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                textview.setText("your string here");

                i++;

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
          };
```

Comment: Can you please show me where I should have this code in my application?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
```

Add this line below after inflating the view. I mean in `OncreateView`.

Comment: I have done this, however I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
    var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
```

to this:

```
    TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplay);
```

Bw you should define and inflate your view like this:

```
    LinearLayout view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
        R.layout.fragment_orange, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to use the LinearLayout type for the View, or can I just use the generic View?

Comment: I am not sure about that. you need to try it. but i think you need to define a particular type for your parent view.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
var textView = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDisplay);
```

Change to:

```
TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDisplay);
```

then

```
view.text.setText(message);
```